# getchar() does not recognize horizontal tabs in my input

Tags: c, io, console

Wrote the C console application below to save input to a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 200

int main () {
    int c, x;
    char in[MAXLINE];

    for (x = 0;(c = getchar()) != EOF; ++x){
        in[x] = c;
    }
    return = 0;
}
```

I will be manipulating this string and printing a modified version as output, but before I get to that, I’ve run into a problem— whenever I step through the code with GDB and a watch window, it completely ignores horizontal tabs.  I even tried writing a workaround:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 200

int main () {
    int c, x;
    char in[MAXLINE];

    for (x = 0;(c = getchar()) != EOF; ++x){
        if (c == 9)
            in[x] = '\t';
        else
            in[x] = c;
    }
    return = 0;
}
```

But this performs in exactly the same way as the first example.  How can I get my code to recognize tabs in my input, and to save them to an array element as such?

EDIT:  Here is my actual code.  It compiles with no errors for me on CodeBlocks, and I've never had a problem with CodeBlock s swallowing nonprint characters before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 100

int main () {
    int c, q, x, y, z, tabcount;
    char in[MAXLINE];
    char out[MAXLINE];

    for (x = 0;(c = getchar()) != EOF; ++x){
        in[x] = c;
    }

    q = x;
    for (x = y = 0; x <= q; ++x) {
        tabcount = 0;
        if (in[x] == '\t') {
            ++tabcount;
            if (tabcount <= 4) {
                for (z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
                    out[y] = ' ';
                    ++y;
                }
            }
            else
                out[y] = '\n';
        }
        else
            out[y] = in[x];
        ++y;
    }
    in[x] = '\0';

    printf ("%s", out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try redirecting `stdin` to a file and put the tab in the redirected file. Does it still work?

Comment: Are you running that from some kind of IDE? Maybe the IDE is swallowing the tabs.

Comment: `return = 0;` doesn't compile.  Otherwise, after correcting this problem,  the program you've shown works for me running in gdb w/ gcc on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm guessing what you posted (since it doesn't compile) is not your actual code.  Either post your actual code, or come up with minimal example and verify it produces the behavior you are claiming to see..

Comment: You didn't change anything....

Comment: That's helpful, but it doesn't address the problem.  There won't be any tabs to count because getchar() skips over them in the initial for loop.

Comment: `out[]` is not null character terminated.  It is not a string.  `printf ("%s", out);` is UB.  Perhaps you meant `out[y] = '\0';`   Early code snippets do not null character terminate `x[]`.

Comment: `x <= q` --> `x < q`, because `x` was incremented in the previous loop, before it met the exit condition.

Comment: Start with `while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) printf("%d\n", c);`. If that doesn't print 9 for the tab key, then the problem has nothing to do with your code. Note that if you're running the code inside a debugger inside an IDE, then the debugger and/or the IDE are probably stealing the TAB keys.

Comment: Always check for possible buffer overflow when dealing with C arrays. (both on your `getchar()` loop and the output loop). Use meaningful variable names.  Use braces for your else conditions.  Is `tabcount` ever supposed to be reset to zero?    You are probably incrementing `y` an extra time.

Comment: the code block that checks for the end of the input: `for (x = 0;(c = getchar()) != EOF; ++x){` will usually not produce the desired results. because stdin, from a keyboard, will only have EOF when the user specifically enters <ctrl-d> (<ctrl-z> on some OSs)  What I think you really want to use is: `while( x<(MAXLINE-1) && (c = getchar()) != EOF &&   '\n' != c )`,

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) use the optional braces for the `else` code blocks 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line 3) use variable names that indicate content or usage or (better) both.

Comment: the array `out[]` will contain more characters than array `in[]` therefore, the array `out[]` needs to be significantly longer than array `in[]`.  otherwise, a full array `in[]` will result in overflowing the array `out[]`

Comment: this code block: `if (c == 9)` is a waste of code space. just assign the `c` to `in[x]`

Comment: in the last posted code, this code block: `if (tabcount <= 4) {` needs to include `tabcount = 0;` in the `else` block

Comment: at the end of this code block: `for (x = y = 0; x <= q; ++x) {`,  is the statement: `y++;`  but that should not be executed when the input char was a <tab>.   Suggest placing the `y++;` statement in each of the `else` code blocks and removing it from the current location at the end of the `for()` code block.   Otherwise, `y` gets incremented once too often when a <tab> is being processed

Answer (score 0):

When modified to  make sure `y` is only incremented once per output char, this works just fine--provided you don't overflow input or output buffers.  Comments added to show where you have the potential to overrun your buffers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 100

int main () {
    int c, q, x, y, z, tabcount;
    char in[MAXLINE];
    char out[MAXLINE];

    for (x = 0;(c = getchar()) != EOF; ++x){ 
        in[x] = c; // <--- OVERFLOW CAN HAPPEN IF INPUT > 100 chars
    }

    q = x;
    for (x = y = 0; x <= q; ++x) {
        tabcount = 0;
        if (in[x] == '\t') {
            ++tabcount;
            if (tabcount <= 4) {
                for (z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
                    out[y] = ' '; // <-- Can overflow here too
                    ++y;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                out[y] = '\n';   // <-- And here
                ++y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            out[y] = in[x];  // <-- and here
            ++y;
            /* I'm guessing you probably want to do tabcount=0 here 
             * if the goal is 5x tab-separated fields per line. */
        }
    }
    in[x] = '\0'; // <-- AND HERE!

    printf ("%s", out);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is UB per [`out` is not a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852973/getchar-does-not-recognize-horizontal-tabs-in-my-input#comment59372772_35852973) and [reading uninitialized `in[q]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852973/getchar-does-not-recognize-horizontal-tabs-in-my-input#comment59372888_35852973)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out GDB and/or CodeBlocks is stealing my tabs.  If I compile/build/run the save-input-to-string application, it prints tabs just fine.  Apparently I just can't debug the larger program or any programs that need to recognize tabs as input, which is weird and irritating.